# Conic Equation Simplification

Tags: conic-sections

Lets say that given the foci and directrix of a hyperbola we solve for the conic equation to be $$16x^2-16y^2=256$$ Is it possible to divide by $16$ and simplify to $$x^2-y^2=16$$ or is that "not allowed"? I did so and was told I was wrong.

Comment: It's fine, represents the same points. Maybe whoever said it was "wrong" wanted the "standard form" $x^2/(4^4)-y^2/(4^2)=1.$

Comment: Oops, in above comment the first denominator should just be $4^2$ not $4^4.$